# How to implement a horizontal cat?

Tags: text-processing, files, scripting, cat

Standard `cat` concatenates files line by line (row by row, if you will). I find myself needing a *horizontal* `cat` command more and more often recently; i.e. a command that takes a list of files and concatenates them horizontally, column by column. So far I’ve used ad-hoc workarounds but I’d like to know if there exists a good solution for this.

To clarify, consider the following comparison between `cat` and `hcat` of two files:

```
$ cat a.dat 1.dat
a b
c d
1 2
3 4
$ hcat -s ' ' a.dat 1.dat
a b 1 2
c d 3 4
```

(Unlike for `cat` we need to specify a separator since by convention UNIX files don’t have a column separator at the end.)

Comment: So, I'm doing it wrong?  http://us.123rf.com/400wm/400/400/ladyminnie/ladyminnie0809/ladyminnie080900009/3520831-lazy-domestic-cat-laying-down-to-sleep.jpg

Comment: @Iszi In the C++ chat I actually wrote “in before longcat is long” when posting the link, to prevent precisely that :p

Comment: Ah, *longcat*!  That's the search term I should have been looking for!

Comment: Longcat is quite vertical though… and long.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This sounds like a job for paste:

```
paste -d ' ' a.dat 1.dat
```

Output:

```
a b 1 2
c d 3 4
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks. That was easier than anticipated.

Comment: note that the default `-d` value is `tab`